# Button call "main" onTouch instead of his own

Tags: android, button, ontouch

im creating app where we can move button with finger. It's ok if I dont press button but if i do, he is calling his own function instead of "main" onTouch

Exemplary code:

```
       final Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setText("Something");
        b.setX(50);
        b.setY(50);
        b.setId((int) 1);
           b.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
           @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
              return false;
            }
        });
        layout.addView(b);
```

And he is calling his own function and i want him to call this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    moving();
}
```

Is there a way to call second onTouch from Button onTouch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implemented the "main" onTouch in the Activity

```
b.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Otherwise, just call that method

```
b.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        moving():
        return false;
    }
});
```